# Practical meaning of expected value, standard deviation & correlation

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, expected-value, cross-correlation

*We've got given annual results of two stock companies described with following values:*

***Company X:*** expected value $\mu_X=0.05$, standard deviation $\sigma_X=0.02$

***Company Y:*** expected value $\mu_Y=0.07$, standard deviation $\sigma_Y=0.03$

*We also know that a cross correlation between results of company X and Y is $\rho=-0.5, \rho=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{var(X)var(Y)}}$. How do we should divide **z** dollars between these companies to obtain:*

*a) maximum revenue (expected return on a portfolio)?*

*b) minimum risk (variance of a portfolio)?*

I don't even expect a full solution, just a brief explanation which would help me to understand a practical meaning of above values.

Comment: Wondering if there's a bit of context missing. Sounds like a question after the introduction of an algorithm which takes those inputs as values and computes how to optimize revenue or risk..?

Comment: So you have to allocate a proportion $p$ of $z$ (i.e. $pz$) dollars to X and $(1-p)z$ dollars to Y. (hint: make $z=1$ to start with - if you allocate $p$ to X and $1-p$ to Y, what is the mean and variance of revenue?)

Comment: $E(revenue)=p\mu_X+(1-p)\mu_Y \quad Var(revenue)=p\rho_X^2+(1-p)\rho_Y^2+2cov(X,Y)$ Do I get it right?

Comment: I think I missed sth and it should be $2p(1-p)cov(X,Y)$. Then I need to find $max E$ and $min Var$?

Comment: Kozooh, this question is not well defined: because the returns for the two assets are random, the revenue cannot be optimized. However, some properties of its *distribution* can be optimized, such as *expected revenue,* or *chance that the revenue exceeds a predetermined threshold.*  Please edit your post to address this point. As far as optimizing the risk (usually defined as the negative of the expected loss) goes, you have enough information to write it as a function of the *proportion* of the $z$ dollars allocated to asset $X$. Use Calculus (or algebra) to minimize that function.

Comment: @whuber, question is well defined as the two bullets a) and b) are separate tasks. Glen_b, thanks for hints, you were right, I got to found a maximum of E and a minimum of Var which is ultimately $p^2\rho_X^2+(1-p)^2\rho_Y^2+2p(1-p)cov(X,Y)$ since $var(aX)=a^2var(X)$.

Comment: Perhaps I did not express myself with sufficient clarity: your question needs to take care to explain what it means to "maximize revenue" because revenue, being *explicitly* a random variable, cannot be maximized. You probably want to maximize some property of that random variable.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I probably should put revenue inside quotation marks. I also found a nice document which also helped me to understand the problem - http://www.ohio.edu/people/prevost/FIN 341/Chapter 6.docx